# SAS Heteroscedasticity and Autocorrelation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity

I did a white test for heteroscedasticity problem and got the following:
DF=27,  Chi-Square=33.91,  Pr>ChiSq=0.1688
Do I have heteroscedasticity?
How do I know?

Also Durbin Watson test showed to be:
Durbin-Watson D=1.672, Number of Obs=171, 1st order autocorrelation=0.162
Do I have autocorrelation problem?

Comment: Why not use heteroscedasticity consistent robust standard errors to eliminate the need for excessive testing?

Comment: I need to do the test. Please help me with the info above?